# replace a key in a file by a sentence with spaces and special characters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, mutt

I searched a means to replace an identified key in a file html by an sentence with spaces and special characters. I tried to use `sed` but I'd get many errors because the sentence may contains many characters.

My shell script :

```
 ...
 cp $HTML_TEMPLATE $HTML_OUTPUT
 sed "s/\@mail_title/$HTML_TITLE/g" $HTML_OUTPUT > temp && mv -f temp $HTML_OUTPUT
 sed "s/\@mail_body/$HTML_CONTENT/g" $HTML_OUTPUT > temp && mv -f temp $HTML_OUTPUT
 ...
```

The goal is to replace in mail.html two keys (`@mail_body` and `@mail_title`) by 2 text variables (`BODY_HTML_TITLE="Report Statistics -$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"`  and `BODY_HTML_CONTENT="test"`) with the script.

mail.html   :

```
....
<table id="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Header -->
      <table id="header">
       <tr>
         <td>
           <table width="100%">
           <tr>
             <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-size:15px; line-height:18px; color:#b5397a; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"> <h2>@mail_title</h2></td>

              </tr>
              ...
```

Comment: try single quoting the bash variables in the `sed` command. So something like `sed 's/\@mail_title/'$HTML_TITLE'/g' $HTML_OUTPUT > temp && mv -f temp $HTML_OUTPUT
 sed 's/\@mail_body/'$HTML_CONTENT'/g' $HTML_OUTPUT > temp && mv -f temp $HTML_OUTPUT`

Comment: you can use double quotes as well

Comment: Consider using `sed -i` for in-place editing of files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it'ok with simple quote, i try to specify html in variable text $HTML_CONTENT in this case the sed replace crash, there is no way to escape all content in final expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your question has following sed statements:

```
sed "s/\@mail_title/$HTML_TITLE/g" $HTML_OUTPUT > temp && mv -f temp $HTML_OUTPUT
sed "s/\@mail_body/$HTML_CONTENT/g" $HTML_OUTPUT > temp && mv -f temp $HTML_OUTPUT
```

However, the target variables (BODY_HTML_TITLE & BODY_HTML_TITLE) that you're mentioning below are *different* from what you've mentioned in the *sed* lines (HTML_TITLE & HTML_CONTENT):

```
BODY_HTML_TITLE="Report Statistics -$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
BODY_HTML_CONTENT="test"
```

Is it a *typo* in your script? My test script works perfectly fine when i'm using the correct variables:

```
[gc@slave1 ~]$ cat file
HTML_TITLE="Report Statistics -$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
echo $HTML_TITLE

<tr>
     <td Arial, sans-serif;"> <h2>@mail_title</h2></td>
</tr>


[gc@slave1 ~]$ cat main
sed "s/@mail_title/$HTML_TITLE/g" file


[gc@slave1 ~]$ ./main
HTML_TITLE="Report Statistics -$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
echo $HTML_TITLE

<tr>
     <td Arial, sans-serif;"> <h2>Report Statistics -2014-08-05</h2></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: BODY_HTML_TITLE is HTML_TITLE, the sed is called in function which have parameters (BODY_HTML_TITLE and BODY_HTML_CONTENT). Sorry for missing to explain that.

Comment: Can you print the error you are getting? Also, can you put the sed lines in printf and show us what you get as output? It might help.